# How to check if any property is absent in json schema

Tags: json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I have to validate json with json-schema with below validation rule.

1 property(prop1) present with only whitespaces, other 2 properties(prop2, prop3) are absent - validation should pass

In below json, first json object should fail and second object should pass.

**json**

```
[
    {
        "prop1": " ",
        "prop2": "Property2",
        "prop3": "Property3"
    },
    {
        "prop1": "   ",
    }
]
```

I found how to check if property is present using "required" keyword, but couldn't find anything for checking if property is absent.

Please suggest json schema to achieve this validation rule.

Comment: In the future, instead of "please suggest _X_," please provide examples of things you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

Your requirements are a bit vague and confusing...

This is my interpretation of them.

The following constraints are applied:

```
#pattern
- [^\\s]  // negated set of whitespace characters
- .  // matches any character except line breaks
- *  // 0 or more of the preceding token
```

##### passing schemas

- `prop1`, `prop2`, `prop3` are optional(not required) properties
- all 3 properties present with valid values
- none of the `prop1`, `prop2`, `prop3` present

##### failing schemas

- all 3 properties present with invalid values
- 1 property present with invalid value, other 2 properties present with valid values
- only 1 property present with invalid value, other 2 are absent
- any combination of `prop1`, `prop2`, `prop3` present with no value, e.g. `""` or only spaces `"    "`

```json
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
    "type": "array",
    "items": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
            "prop1": {
                "type": "string",
                "pattern": "[^\\s].*"
            },
            "prop2": {
                "type": "string",
                "pattern": "[^\\s].*"
            },
            "prop3": {
                "type": "string",
                "pattern": "[^\\s].*"
            },
            "prop4": {
                "type": "string"
            }
        },
        "required": [
        "prop4"
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but my requirement is different. Edited the question which explains my problem in a better way.

Comment: is your data actually returning empty whitespace in property values? This seems like a very contrived example. Can you explain with more detail why this would happen? Your example data instance is nonsensical. You can't say `prop1` exists with whitespace and must not have additional properties and then say it can exist with whitespace AND  additional properties.  `prop1` doesn't have any distinct differences between those two scenarios